# Spark Streaming jobs exception handling

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

In my spark streaming(Kafka Consumer) code have some error. I am implemented the exception handling but that never caught. I tried both checked & unchecked exceptions.

My code is running in the executor. How I catch the exception when it is running in executor instead of driver ?

Please suggest me.

Comment: code snippet could be helpful to uderstand your problem and recommend 
 fix?

Answer (score 0):

Spark is a parallel framework. Even you add try catch code in your code, but the exception is thrown in other threads. So your code can not catch any exception.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Even it is running in multiple executors only.
If anyone know how to resolve it then plz explain here.